# 3rd Party Vulnerabilities Fix (Access to source code vs no access to source code)

Tags: source-code, opensource, embedded-system

I've embedded system software with listed vulnerabilities from a static code analyser tool. Since it is an embedded system, and I don't have access to some of the source code (being 3rd party) for which vulnerabilities have to be fixed, what can I do in this scenario?

Access to source code = no issue, all bugs can be fixed.

It is only a specific question where access to source code is not available.

Comment: Be wary of fixing vulnerabilities by decompiling / fixing / recompiling as any subsequent patch from the official vendor might not be applicable anymore

Comment: How did you run code analysis without having access to source code? I mean the part you said it's 3rd party and don't have access to it.

Comment: I already mentioned that its embedded system and a good portion of it is from 3rd Party i.e. code generated by Google Proto Buff code generator. You can

Comment: you run it basically from build environment. If that helps your question.

Answer (score 1):

In that scenario, I would reach out to the vendor. If you are one of their customers you should have a support model for ongoing issues. If it was developed or purchased with no ongoing support you might have to pay for a update. You should come up with a options paper for management eg:

1. Do nothing and the risks associated
2. Have company abc develop and publish a update
3. Purchase a up to date competing application with ongoing support
4. Mitigate the vulnerability some how (Cant expand as haven't got the details)

Comment: As I mentioned that its an open source tool like  "Google Proto Buff code generator" where the access to the code is not possible. You just input your data here and code is generated.

Comment: You didn't clearly mention in your question that the tool is "Open Source" but your saying the source code isn't available so its not really open source then.

Your business made a choice when they went with this solution, They opted for a solution that provides decreased supportability and now they are paying for it. Its all now down to a financial decision from the business.